# PHP array merge with manual entry

Tags: php

I have this array in PHP:

```
array:2 [
  "username" => array:1 [
    0 => "The username field is required."
  ]
  "password" => array:1 [
    0 => "The password confirmation does not match."
  ]
]
```

I want to add an element manually like this:

```
array:3 [
  "username" => array:1 [
    0 => "The username field is required."
  ]
  "password" => array:1 [
    0 => "The password confirmation does not match."
  ]
  "type" => array:1 [
    0 => "error"
  ]
]
```

`$responseBag` contains the first array, I am doing combinations of this with no luck:

```
array_push($responseBag, ['type' => 'error']);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$responseBag['type'] = ['error'];`

Comment: `$responseBag = array_merge($responseBag, ['type' => 'error'])` or what @CBroe suggested. You have multiple options now (I prefer his).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
$responseBag['type'][] = 'error';
```

Comment: Please put more effort into this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to stay away from array_push in general. For simple stuff like this, I would simply use

```
$responseBag['type'] = ['error'];
```

Or you could merge the existing array with a new one, as Mjh suggested:

```
$responseBag = array_merge($responseBag, ['type' => 'error']);
```

array_push won’t really work here - that does not allow you to specify the key; the purpose of that one rather is to add new elements to the end of a numerically indexed array.